# Performance: View or Query

Tags: sql, database

Suppose I have a SQL Query that isn't really "nice".

The SQL Query has a lot inner join with long conditions, and finally a simple "where" statement.

Now suppose I make a View that corresponds to that SQL Query, excepting the final "where" statement. So that instead of make that long query, I use the view and simply add the "where" statement.

My question is the following:
Which one would have best performance?

I'm not sure if the "View" option corresonds to two sql statement, instead of the one sql statement of the first option. Or before executing the query, the "View" query is "pasted" in the more simple query and is "the same".

Comment: Why downvote ? It seems a good question.

Comment: I didn't downvote you ... and views have many advantages ... but "performance" (at least in this case) certainly isn't one of them ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference.  The view uses the same query as the query alone.

To be different it would need to store it in a view table view don't, they're just queries made to look easy from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the DBMS you're using has a cost-based query optimizer, you'll probably not get any better performance when a portion of the query is converted to a view. You can confirm this with your database's query explain tool by comparing the estimated cost of both versions of the query.

I recommend using the query explain utility to determine exactly where the query becomes expensive, since the location of a query's pain points are often unexpected. It may seem that all those joins are slowing things down, but they may be exploiting indexes that minimize the I/O and CPU cycles required to connect the rows. Many times the query bogs down because an unindexed column is referenced in a WHERE or ON clause.

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong, but I was expecting that using the View would give me worse performance, because I guessed that would imply two querys, the first to get the view table and the second that use that table to filter with the "where". Thanks for your reply

Comment: A statement that references a view will still be handled as one statement by the optimizer. Internally, the optimizer is just grabbing the SQL for the view and dropping it into the spot in your query where the view is referenced. It's unlikely that referencing views will even affect the amount of time it takes the optimizer to parse your query, resolve the table references, and come up with what it considers to be the best access plan that takes the tables' indexing, cardinality, and data distribution into account.

Comment: There is no relation between the type of optimizer and whether a view performs better than an ad-hoc query.